# How to use jdk.internal package with Gradle?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, jvm, gradle-kts

For example, if I'd like to add an extension on `Inet4Address` to be able to directly retrieve the underlying 32-bit address as an `Int`:

```kotlin
import jdk.internal.access.SharedSecrets

val Inet4Address.value
        get() = SharedSecrets.getJavaNetInetAddressAccess().addressValue(this)
```

IntelliJ IDEA does not show any errors, auto-complete works fine for it, etc.

However, when Gradle `compileKotlin` runs, I get these compilation errors:

```
Unresolved reference: access
Unresolved reference: SharedSecrets
```

This happens despite using a Java 11 toolchain spec in my `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(11))
    }
}
```

How can I go about giving Kotlin access to the `jdk.internal` package with Gradle?

Comment: You basically need the `--add-exports` option for kotlinc, but I don't think that exists yet.

Comment: Note that `Inet4Address.hashCode()` returns the same value as `addressValue()` without accessing JDK internal APIs (and thus does not requires `--add-exports`).

Comment: Is this some special reflex some developers have? Seeing “internal” in the name of an API and responding with “must…use…this…API”?